# Compile-time check a value to implement several interfaces

Tags: c#, types, interface

Let's say I want to express "**a method that expect an object which implements interfaces IFoo and IBar**". Something like:

```
void Method(IFoo+IBar param);
```

**How can I say this using C# ?**

*(Is there a syntaxical construct? Or a good idiom perhaps?)*

---

### An attempt

Introduce an interface:

```
interface IFooBar : IFoo, IBar {}

void Method(IFooBar param);
```

**This is bad** and I regret even thinking of it :-) Looks OK at the first glance, but the sad part is that silently introduces a dependency which shouldn't be here.

The sole reason for `IFooBar` to exist is to be a part of `Method`'s interface. Hence, any class of objects to be used as `Method`'s parameter must know that this method (and that interface) exist - which wouldn't be the case otherwise. All classes implementing IFoo and IBar would need to be modified to also implement IFooBar (possibly getting to know a new assembly) - which is heavily impractical, or even impossible if we can't modify them.

Unnecessary dependency = a no-go.

### A workaround

Give up static typing:

```
void Method(object param)
{
    if (!param is IFoo)
        throw new ArgumentException("IFoo not supported", "param");
    if (!param is IBar)
        throw new ArgumentException("IBar not supported", "param");

    // ...
}
```

*(or: define one type in signature and dynamically check the others - preferable if one is the most important, but even more confusing)*

Works correcty, but in run-time (no compile-time check). Desperately requires a doc (and everyone to read it).

Also only practical in function parameters. The code'd get massively bloated with casts if I tried to use that on a field.

---

A real case for this situation? For instance `IList<Foo>` + `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I like the workaround with the generic method :-) Pity I can't have generic properties. I think I'll use a generic `getX()` / `setX()` pair instead when I need one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
public void someMethod<T>(T param) where T : IFoo, IBar
{...}
```

Answer (score 2):

A friend of mine once asked Eric Lippert a very similiar question, and this was his response:

> Q: Is there a reason C# doesn’t allow for declaring a variable by
>   multiple interfaces?
>
> A: Let’s say that we annotate it as {IFoo, IBar}.
>
> The problem is bigger than declaring variables. Essentially you are
>   saying that you want to change the constraint on a variable from “the
>   variable must be of the given type” to “the variable must be all of
>   several given types”. But why stop at variables? If that’s the type
>   constraint of a variable then that should be a type, period.  You
>   should be able to say:
>
> ```
> List< { IFoo, IBar } > myList; Or
> ```

```
 public static { IFoo, IBar } MyMethod( { IFoo, IBar }[ ] foobars  )
 {  return foobars[0];  }
```

> And so on. No point in doing the feature halfway.
>
> This would be a major extension to the type system. We’d want to
>   support it in *every* managed language, not just C# and VB. This is
>   the sort of feature that you want to get into the framework in version
>   one; it is very expensive and difficult to make such a major change
>   when you’re four versions in and have billions of lines of customer
>   code that has to keep on working.
>
> I have often wanted that feature myself; I agree that it is a nice
>   feature, but I think it is simply too expensive to add it now.  Next
>   time you design a new type system, include that feature from the
>   beginning!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by defining your method as below

```
void Method<T>(T param) 
    where T: IFoo, IBar
{
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

One can use constrained generic parameters for things which will not be persisted after a method returns.  Unfortunately, there's a major limitation with them.  A method such as:

```
void foo(T param) where T:IFoo,IBar {...}
```

is easy to call if one knows at compile time that `T` is *some particular type* which implements `IFoo` and `IBar`.  Unfortunately, it is difficult to construct a collection of objects which can be passed to a routine like the above without them all sharing a common base type which implements both interfaces.  If one wants to try to hold a collection of 
"things that implement both `IFoo` and `IBar`, and can be passed to routines expecting same", there are ways of doing it, but they're not easy.

If one can identify in advance all the routines to which one might want to pass the objects one is given, one can have the collection create closed generic delegates for each object one is given, at the time one is given it.  This will work, and may be reasonably efficient, in those situations where it is workable.  It does, however, introduce very strong dependencies between the collection class and the use of objects in the collection.

A somewhat more versatile approach is to have the collection hold wrapper objects that support a method to perform an arbitrary constrained-open-generic actions upon their inner objects.  Unfortunately, delegates won't work well for this, since .net does not provide any mechanism for calling open generic delegates without first using Reflection to convert them to closed form.  Instead, one must define interfaces like:

```
interface IActUpon<T,U> {
  void DoSomething<MT>(ref MT it) where MT:T,U;
}
interface IActUpon<T,U,PT1> {
  void DoSomething<MT>(ref MT it, ref PT1 p1) where MT:T,U;
}
interface IActUpon<T,U,PT1,PT2> {
  void DoSomething<MT>(ref MT it, ref PT1 p1, ref PT2 p2) where MT:T,U;
}
```

If an object supports a method family of methods:

```
void DoSomethingWithMe(IActUpon<T,U> proc);
void DoSomethingWithMe(IActUpon<T,U,PT1> proc, ref PT1 p1);
void DoSomethingWithMe(IActUpon<T,U,PT1,PT2> proc, ref PT1 p1, ref PT2 p2);
```

one can have the object call any desired routine which requires a parameter constrained to types T and U, by creating a simple class which implements the appropriate variation of `IActUpon<T,U,...>`.

Unfortunately, while that approach is nearly general (the biggest limitation being that one must explicitly code for any particular number of generic parameters) it's awkward at best.  With some compiler support it might not be too bad, but otherwise it's probably too icky for general use.